# Calculating equations of lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given the line $d : 2x + 3y + 4 = 0$, find the equation of a line $d1$ passing through the point
$M_0(2, 1)$, in the following situations:
(a) $d1$ is parallel with $d$;
(b) $d1$ is orthogonal on $d$;
(c) the angle determined by $d$ and $d1$ is $ϕ =
π
/4$.

Can somebody give me some tips please on how to solve these?

I've only managed to calculated tha $m_d= -\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Parallel: you need the slopes to be equal.  Orthogonal, you need the slopes to be negative reciprocals of each other....

Comment: ok, thank you! Thats's not hard to get. And do you have any ideas for the point c?

Comment: @Gaboru, substitute $(2,1)$ to find $c$

Comment: For part (c), you could use the dot product to find a unit vector that for the desired angle with $d$. Note, there are two answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you could use:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=m_{d1}
\end{equation*}

Where:

\begin{align*}
x_0&=2\\y_0&=1
\end{align*}

Then:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{y-1}{x-2}=m_{d1}
\end{equation*}

Case (a): $m_{d1}=-\dfrac{2}{3}$, Since $m_{d1}=m_{d}$

Case (b): $m_{d1}=\dfrac{3}{2}$, Since $m_{d1}m_{d}=-1$

Case (c): To find $m_{d1}$ you could use:

$\tan(\alpha+\pi/4)=\dfrac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\pi/4)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\pi/4)}$

being: $\tan(\alpha)=m_d$ and $\tan(\alpha+\pi/4)=m_{d1}$ we have:

$m_{d1}=\dfrac{m_d+1}{1-m_d}$

then:

$m_{d1}=\dfrac{2}{15}$